# How to run specific tests with frisby?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, frisby.js

We are using frisby to run our integration tests and while developing them, it would be handy to execute one specific one or a group of tests, without having run all of them and see extra noise.  Right now I am commenting out all the ones I don't want to run, which is getting tedious.

Is there a way, from the command line, to run specific frisby tests?

So basically, instead of

```
npm test
```

I want to be able to say

```
npm test --name: posts
```

Or something like that.  I found [this](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/65) post about jasmine-only, but I'm not sure it will satisfy my needs.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for answer, but this is pretty simple.

Firstly install latest version of jasmine-node from command line: `npm install jasmine-node -g`

Then to run particular test use: `jasmine-node --coffee putTestNameHere`

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out.

Comment: Great! Be sure that you are in correct project catalog while running the test, just like using npm test.

Answer (score 1):

Install jasmine-node module. Execute one file at a time - you can group your test cases in specific file:

jasmin-node moduleTestCases_spec.js

Also, if you want to specify exact test case name to be executed, you can make use of sequenty module. It is a nodejs module, which you can specify the order(and thus the exact test cases to execute).

Comment: I will try those out, thanks!  For the first suggestion, if I split them in files, is there a way to run them all at once as well, so I can run individual or all of them when and how I choose?

Comment: jasmine-node *_spec.js will execute everything, one by one.

or you can write a script to invoke jasmine-node command from a list of file names.

Answer (score 0):

To run specific test in Frishby just run:

```
npm test ./folder/filename.js
```

So lets assume you have an folder say `test` under that you have a file called `api.spec.js`
then you will execute like this:

```
npm test ./test/api.spec.js
```

Parallely don't forget to specify these below things into your `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"  }
```